# Navigation view's menu items are unable to navigate to navigate to their respective destinations

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation-drawer

I am attempting to implement a navigation drawer with navigation component.My Navigation view contains menuItems that can be used to navigate to their respective destinations via their ids.
The rest of the app is working well, but the problem lies in the navigationView.
The menuItem ids all correspond to navigation destinations, and i am certain that a it has access to a navController to navigate to its respective destinations. I woould appreciate any advice or solutions from experience.

```
    class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private lateinit var appBarConfiguration: AppBarConfiguration
private lateinit var navController: NavController
private lateinit var drawerLayout: DrawerLayout
private lateinit var navigationView: NavigationView
private lateinit var navHost: NavHostFragment


private lateinit var listener: NavController.OnDestinationChangedListener
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "app booted up", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    
    navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_drawer)
    drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout)
    navHost = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host) as NavHostFragment
   
    navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host)
   
    appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(navController.graph,drawerLayout)
  
  setupActionBarWithNavController(navController,appBarConfiguration)
            navigationView.setupWithNavController(navController)
}
override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
    val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host)
    return navController.navigateUp(appBarConfiguration) || super.onSupportNavigateUp()//we have to specify the drawerLayout.
}
```

}

```
         /**menu for navigation view
          <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
          <menu xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"> 
          <group>
           android:checkableBehavior="single">
           <item android:title = "@string/coffee_man_option_1"
           android:id  = "@id/home"/>
           <item android:title = "@string/coffee_man_option_2"
            android:id  = "@id/testFragment"/>
            </group>
            </menu>

      /** navigation graph **/
       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
       <navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
         xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" 
         android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
app:startDestination="@id/home">
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/home"
    android:name="com.example.coffeeman.Home"
    android:label="Home"
    tools:layout="@layout/home_screen">
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_home_to_testFragment"
        app:destination="@id/testFragment" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
     android:id="@+id/testFragment"
     tools:layout="@layout/test_view"
    android:name="com.example.coffeeman.testFragment"
    android:label="testFragment" >
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_testFragment_to_home"
        app:destination="@id/home" />
</fragment>
```

Answer (score 0):

invoking bringToFront() on the navigation view allows the items to be responsive.

```
    navigationView.bringtoFront()
```